# How to find data source for TravelDistance function?

Tags: curated-data

Just a quick one. I've been using the `TravelDistance` function for some analysis. I want to cite the data source used by Mathematica, but can't find any reference to that information. Does anyone know a) how to find that information, or b) what the source is?

Answer (score 2):

Answer [from Wolfram Community Forum](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/967064?p_p_auth=4S4OcfjM): 
We are using GraphHopper deployment as internal engine, and it uses data dump from OpenStreetMap.

Thanks to Francisco Rodríguez!